# In Lucene.net, I want to do an AND within the same facet category but there appears to be no simple way to do this

Tags: c#, lucene.net, facet

We have a client that wants to set up an ingredients facet. So a product item would have a Facet that would contain all of the ingredients. Given to lucene as a multi value field.

what I want when someone something in this facet is for the pool of items to always get bigger. I don't want something with chocolate or nuts I want chocolate AND nuts but it doesn't seem like there is an easy way to get lucene to do this.

My only thought so far is to create a drilldown query and drilldown on that item and then in a loop pass that as the base query to another drilldown query.

Is there a better way to handle this scenario?

```
if (facet != null && facet.IsLogicalAnd)
{
    foreach (var option in selectedFacet.Options)
    {
        q.Add(selectedFacet.Name, option);
        q = new DrillDownQuery(_facetsConfig, q);
    }
}
```

That's my current workaround code fyi

Comment: Let's not be too quick to close this.  This is actually a pretty interesting question and I'm not sure what the answer is.  He is asking if it's possible to select documents based on an AND of two different values of the same facet rather than an AND of two different facets.  I too would like to know the answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about facets or about `DrillDownQuery`, but you could use a `BooleanQuery`. 
You could do:

```
var query = new BooleanQuery();
query.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("Ingredient","Chocolate")));
query.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("Ingredient","Nuts")));
```

Of course for this to work, you would need to add the ingredients as "simple" fields in the index, not just as facet fields

**Update 18-12-2019**

It just so happened that I started working with Lucene facets at work too, and found a solution for this problem. It looks something like this:

```
var drillDownQuery = new DrillDownQuery(facetsConfig, baseQuery);

var boolQuery = new BooleanQuery();
boolQuery.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("Ingredient", "Chocolate")), Occur.MUST);
boolQuery.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("Ingredient", "Nuts")), Occur.MUST);
drillDownQuery.Add("Ingredient", boolQuery);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: It just would require a lot of special handling around this to make it work, it doesn't fit in with the rest of our relatively configurable setup well.
I still need the ingredients to be displayed as a facet on the client site which means that it needs to be returned as part of the facet, with counts and options.
I don't think lucene has a great solution for this. My checking a config switch and looping through successive drilldown queries works but it is kind of a black spot it what is otherwise pretty good looking code.

Comment: hey @BrandonWest, I think I found a solution for this. I edited the answer with additional stuff

Comment: This causes me to get a zero back for every count in this facet.
I'm not sure if term query is able to find a facet field.
I think I'd have to duplicate my facet fields into text field or something in order to use this approach. Which is sad because it's less convoluted than my current approach. But i'm not sure how big I want to make my index with extra stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with this update it would be better, you can use only facet fields.

```
var drillDownQuery = new DrillDownQuery(facetsConfig, baseQuery);
string indexFieldName = facetConfig.GetDimConfig("Ingredient").IndexFieldName;

var boolQuery = new BooleanQuery();
boolQuery.Add(new TermQuery(DrillDownQuery.Term(indexFieldName, "Ingredient", "Chocolate")), Occur.MUST);
boolQuery.Add(new TermQuery(DrillDownQuery.Term(indexFieldName, "Ingredient", "Nuts")), Occur.MUST);
drillDownQuery.Add("Ingredient", boolQuery);
```